# префикс не отображается в чате | minecraft bukkit 1.16.5 | ESSENTIALS & LUCKPERMS

Tags: minecraft

Заинтересовался разработкой серверов, начал колупать плагины.
Настроил конфиг essentials, создал группу в luckperms, всё работает помимо префикса... Его нет, и в этом проблема. Не работает даже уже с заданными параметрами в конфиге essentials chat

Скриншот проблемы(scr 1), скриншот конфига essentials(scr2), скриншот плагинов(scr3)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Установи Vault и любой чат менеджер. Если новые версии, то лучше ChatManager.